# How to orient the camera to show the object exactly in the same way your eyes are looking at it

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

Do you know if there is a way to align automatically the camera to the user persp view that I have at a certain moment,so that the camera can view exactly what I see in that persp view ? For example,let's see the image below. I want to orient automatically the camera on the x;y axis and with the right rotation needed to show the object exactly how my eyes are looking at it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having your **Camera** selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

[image: final]

[image: second]

When objects are clipped you need to increase **Camera Clipping** range in Camera tab (you will need to have Camera selected):

[image: camera]

Comment: like this ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauSkRVTmhEMlp3bTQ/ ; I did it what you explained,but the camera does not look exactly what I want.

Comment: I think that your edit does not look complete for me,because I'm not able to understand what to do.

Comment: @Marietto this one should be better. You can always look to Blender Docs if you are new in Blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/camera.html

Comment: no,I'm not completely new in blender,but don't give me the blender docs,because it's the most annoying way to learn blender. instead,I'm more satisfied if you want to give me a small video tutorial.

Comment: now I can see your edit...

Comment: now I understood your answer. ok. it works. thanks.

Comment: @Marietto, glad that I could help. Remember that video tutorials or any full blown tutorials aren't welcome here as well as external sources as answers.